# PySpark: Una función que devuelva los registros en los que hay algún not null de los campos insertados por parámetros

Tags: python, pyspark, spark

Mi idea es parametrizar lo siguiente:

```
df.where(col("a").isNotNull() | col("b").isNotNull() | col("c").isNotNull() | col("d").isNotNull())
```

Esto devuelve los registros en los que por lo menos 1 campo es not null

Pero pasando las columnas por una lista:

```
lstCols = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
def x(df, lstCols):
```

Comment: Me imagino que será algo así, pero no estoy seguro si esto lo hace con operadores And u Or: df.where(x.isNotNull() for x in lstCols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He investigado por ahí, y he encontrado la respuesta en el siguiente link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239629/pyspark-dataframe-filter-using-logical-and-over-list-of-conditions-numpy-all

Para mi caso, sería hacer lo siguiente:

Importante hacer los siguientes imports:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

lstCols = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
def x(df, lstCols):
    df.where(reduce(or_, (col(c).isNotNull() for c in lstCols))))
```

Df ejemplo sin where:

```
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
| Id1| Id2| Name| Desc| etc|
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
|   A|   1|Name1|desc1|etc1|
|   B|   1| null|desc2|etc2|
|   B|null| null|desc3|etc3|
|null|null| null|desc4|etc4|
+----+----+-----+-----+----+
```

Df ejemplo con where (en lstCols he metido ["Id1", "Id2"]):

```
+---+----+-----+-----+----+
|Id1| Id2| Name| Desc| etc|
+---+----+-----+-----+----+
|  A|   1|Name1|desc1|etc1|
|  B|   1| null|desc2|etc2|
|  B|null| null|desc3|etc3|
+---+----+-----+-----+----+
```

Ty @zero323

Comment: Buen día, que bueno que encontraste la respuesta, por favor acéptala para ayudar a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Saludos!

Comment: Tenía que esperar 2 días para aceptarla y se me ha pasado, gracias por recordar. @HeytalePazguato

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien a tu pregunta, deseas tener una función que reciba un *DataFrame*, y que filtre los records si estos contienen valores en determinadas columnas, y estas columnas serán pasadas en un array como parámetro a esta función?

Osea:

Si el input es:

```
| uno | dos | tres |
|-----|-----|------|
|   1 |    1|    1 | <- Bueno
|   2 | null|    2 | <- Bueno
|null | null| null | <- Malo
|null | null|    4 | <- Malo
```

Y sólo queremos los rows que tengan o la columna "uno" o "dos" como no nula, entonces nuestra función nos daría esto como resultado?:

```
+---+----+----+
|uno| dos|tres|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   1|   1|
|  2|null|   2|
+---+----+----+
```

Si es así, puedes utilizar la función `coalesce` justo como lo harías en SQL para obtener el primer valor no nulo, de lo contrario tendrías `null`:

```py
def has_needed_columns(df: DataFrame, needed: list) -> DataFrame:
    return df.where(F.coalesce(*needed).isNotNull())
```

Para usar `coalesce` necesitas importar:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

El código completo te queda algo así:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("ex").getOrCreate()


def has_needed_columns(df: DataFrame, needed: list) -> DataFrame:
    return df.where(F.coalesce(*needed).isNotNull())

needed_columns = ["uno", "dos"]

"""Input
| uno | dos | tres |
|_____|_____|______|
|   1 |    1|    1 | <- Bueno
|   2 | null|    2 | <- Bueno
|null | null| null | <- Malo
|null | null|    4 | <- Malo
"""
good_df_with_no_null: DataFrame = spark.sql("""
    select    1 as uno,    1 as dos,    1 as tres""")
good_df_with_one_null: DataFrame = spark.sql("""
    select    2 as uno, null as dos,    2 as tres""")
bad_df_all_null: DataFrame = spark.sql("""
    select null as uno, null as dos, null as tres""")
bad_df_needed_null: DataFrame = spark.sql("""
    select null as uno, null as dos,    4 as tres""")

all_test_df: DataFrame = good_df_with_no_null \
    .union(good_df_with_one_null) \
    .union(bad_df_all_null) \
    .union(bad_df_needed_null)

has_needed_columns(all_test_df, needed_columns).show()
```

Y el resultado que arroja es:

```
+---+----+----+
|uno| dos|tres|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   1|   1|
|  2|null|   2|
+---+----+----+
```